# Cannot change CSS from within ajax .done or .fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I want to use a jQuery ajax call and change some CSS properties of an element if the ajax call succeeds or fails. My broswer is Chrome (latest version) on Windows 7 professional.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "mytesturl",
  dataType: 'json',
  timeout: 3000 // 3 second timeout
}).done(
  function(json) {
    var el = $('#myDiv');
    el.css('color', '#00FF00'); // green
}).fail(
   function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    var el = $('#myDiv');
    el.css('color', '#FF0000'); // red
});
```

If I try this and start / stop the webserver to simulate a success and fail the color does not change at all. :-(.

If I debug I see that the code inside .done and .fail is executed, but the color does not change. The debugger is executing the line `el.css('color', '#FF0000');`. But the browser does not change the color!?!

I checked 'el' returns a valid element but for some reason the browser does not change the color. Also other changes like `el.html('test');` do not work.

If I change the color using a button then the color is changed.
It seems that out of the functions .done / .fail it is not working.
Is there any issue with the scope?

What can it be?

Comment: what is your page's domain and what is the domain of the site you are calling via `ajax`? Are they the same?

Comment: try to put the code to change css inside a setTimeout function.

Comment: Please provide a link to a demo page (i suggest jsbin)

Comment: Without your HTML this question can't be answered. It's likely your selector is wrong

Comment: Do you have multiple element with the same id on the page? i.e. `myDiv`

Comment: if myDiv is a <div> element then set 'background' instead of 'color'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mytesturl",
  dataType: 'json',
  timeout: 3000, // 3 second timeout
  success: function(json) {
              var el = $('#myDiv');
              el.css('color', '#00FF00'); // green
           },
  error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus){
              var el = $('#myDiv');
              el.css('color', '#FF0000'); // red
           }
});
```

ALSO: if you are trying to set the color for a div, color isn't the right option to set, you should set the background like this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "mytesturl",
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 3000, // 3 second timeout
      success: function(json) {
                  var el = $('#myDiv');
                  el.css('background', '#00FF00'); // green
               },
      error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                  var el = $('#myDiv');
                  el.css('background', '#FF0000'); // red
               }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery.ajax({

        type:"post",
        timeout: 3000,
        dataType:"json",
        url: "mytesturl",
        success: function(json) {
             var el = $('#myDiv');
             el.css('color', '#FF0000');   
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var el = $('#myDiv');
            el.css('color', '#000000');
        },
    });
```